# Question about the basis of neighborhoods of a topology $\tau$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I don't understand the definition of that basis of neighborhoods:

> Let $$\tau=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\{0,1,2,3,...,n\}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\mathbb{N}\}$$
>
> Prove that for a $n\in\mathbb{N}$, a basis of neighborhoods is
>
> $$B(n)=\{\{0,1,...,n\}\}$$

How I have to understand that definition of basis? It's the set

$$B(n)=\{\{0,1,...,n\}\}=\{\{0\},\{0,1\},\{0,1,2\},...\}?$$

Or for a particular $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have a basis defined by $B(n)=\{\{{0\}},\{0,1\},\{0,1,2\},...,\{0,1,2,...,n\}\}?$

Thanks!

Comment: $B(n)$ is the unitary set containing the element $\{0,1,\cdots,n\}$. In other words, a point $n\in\mathbb N$ has a basis of only one neighborhood, which is $\{0,1,\cdots, n\}$.

Comment: Okay, perfect, thanks!

Comment: A base (basis) $B$ is $\{B(n):n\in \Bbb N_0\}=$ $\{B(0), B(1), B(2),B(3),...\} $ where $ B(n)=\{0,.., n\}$ .Compare this to what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B(n)$ consists of one set, the single neighbourhood $\{0, 1,2,\ldots, n\}$.

As to the proof: If $O$ is open and $n \in O$ show that $\{0, 1,2,\ldots, n\} \subseteq O$.